# How to stop swf when an error occur

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a project where I am loading in an external swf and when it error loading I want it to show the error on screen which I have accomplished and then I want to provent it from going any further . i.e no more frames entered no more axtionscript run

I tried this and got nothing

```
 function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
error_txt.text = e.text;    
trace(e.target.loaderURL);
stop();
 }
```

Comment: Where exactly does this code live? Is it on the main timeline, or in a MovieClip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the ioError function as an event handler on the LoaderInfo object.  I assume somewhere you've created a Loader to load your external SWF.  Here's the example from Adobe (http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) edited slightly to remove classes.

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("some.swf");
loader.load(request);
addChild(loader);

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
     trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
}
```

Comment: well, yes I didall of  you have here but I that still does stop the rest of what I have going on... however I did figure out what I was doing wrong so I did what I needed to do to prevent the rest of the code from processing using conditional branching